# Skip Laravel scheduled job based on configuration which can be changed via an API call

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled job in a Laravel API which runs every hour. I want to control the execution of the job based on some configuration which can be changed via an API call.

I found following snippet in the Laravel documentation, which shows how to skip a scheduled job:

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')->daily()->skip(function () {
    return true;
});
```

Now I want to check some configuration in this function which determines if the job should be executed.
I thought about a 'system_settings' table in the database which holds a value that determines if the job should be executed or not. In this, case I can change the value with an API call.

Are there any other (simple) methods how this can be done?

Comment: Yes, a database value is the best way to go. You'll just need to set up the endpoint to be able to toggle the setting

Comment: database or cache like redis.